# I get this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'countPoints'

Tags: syntax

When I import this code that I typed in here in to another code I get the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'countPoints' .

```
import ModuleRollDice as dce

def judge(rollPlayerA,rollPlayerB):

    if not all(item in dce.options for item in rollPlayerA) or
       not all(item in dce.options for item in rollPlayerB):
            print("error")

    if rollPlayerA.countPoints(rollPlayerA[0]) == len(rollPlayerA) and
       rollPlayerB.countPoints(rollPlayerB[0]) != len(rollPlayerB):
            return "A"

    if rollPlayerA.countPoints(rollPlayerA[0]) != len(rollPlayerA) and
       rollPlayerB.countPoints(rollPlayerB[0]) == len(rollPlayerB):
            return "B"

    elif sum(rollPlayerA) == sum(rollPlayerB):
        return "tie"

    elif sum(rollPlayerA) > sum(rollPlayerB):
        return "A"

    else:
        return "B"

    return
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the arguments passed to rollPlayerA/B are not list types objects. You should sanity check this beforehand to ensure that what is recieved is in fact a list type object. The issue can be resolved by both sanity checking and looking at the caller function and seeing what is being sent as arguments.

A simple sanity check could look like:

```
def judge(rollPlayerA,rollPlayerB):
    if type(rollPlayerA) is not type(list) or
       type(rollPlayerB) is not type(list):
            print("judge function did not recieve proper input types")
            return

    ...
```

Another way of doing this would be using pythons assert

```
def judge(rollPlayerA,rollPlayerB):
    assert(type(rollPlayerA) == type(list)), "rollPlayerA is not a list"
    assert(type(rollPlayerB) == type(list)), "rollPlayerB is not a list"
```

An even nicer way of doing this would be using PEP 3107's implementation of type assertions in definition declarations:

```
def judge(rollPlayerA: list, rollplayerB: list) -> None:
    ....
```

This also allows you to remove the redundant 'return' statement at the end of your function, which you didn't really need anyways